# Automatically create table structure in an membory based derby database (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I have a simple program I am working on, right now I am working in netbeans and using the derby database, in memory, and have it set to create the database if it doesn't exist.

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/memory:APP;create=true", "APP", "APP");
```

My question is... while it creates the database, it does not create the table structure.. how do I get the program to create that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look at this link](http://www.herongyang.com/jdbc/Derby-Server-CREATE-TABLE.html) it has how to create a table programatically from Java.
[This link](http://www.herongyang.com/jdbc/Derby-Server-INERT-INTO.html) tells you how to populate the table with Data.

Comment: if your using JPA/Hibernate over a derby DB do you have any links that outline the hibernate parameters to set to ensure that schema/tables are created automatically?

Comment: @emeraldjava - Maybe you might want to post that as a question on this site ?